# Singly Linked List - Backward in C

Tags: c

i trying to create this but its hard for me. can some help me and explain for it ?
show menu
ask user to choose input
if user choose 1, then :
check if there any number can divide with 5 or no --> if yes, show all the number that can divide with 5
if user choose 2, then :
check if there any number are odd --> if yes, sum all odd number
if user choose 3, then :
show the highest number & show it
if user choose 4, then :
show the smallest number & show it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node* link;
}NODE;

int main (){
    //assumption : total number = 5
    //1. create 5 node
    for (int i=1; i<=5;i++){
        createNode();
    }
    //repeat step 2 - 4 if choose !=5
    //2. show menu
    //3. ask user to choose input
    //4. if user choose 1, then :
    //      check if there any number can divide with 5 or no --> if yes, show all the number that can divide with 5
    //   if user choose 2, then : 
    //      check if there any number are odd --> if yes, sum all odd number
    //  if user choose 3, then :
    //      show the highest number & show it
    //  if user choose 4, then :
    //      show the smallest number & show it
    
    //4a. choose 1
    if (choose==1){
        for (..............){
            if(newNode->num % 5 == 0 ){
                printf (.............); // show numbers
            }
        }
    }

    //4c. choose 3
    else if (choose==3){
        
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            
        }
    }
    //  5, 3, 10, 4, 1
    
    // assumption the highest = 10
    newNode= head;
    assumption = newNode->bil; 
    for (.........){
        if (newNode->num > assumption ){
            assumption = ....... ;
        }
        newNode = newNode->link;
    }
    printf (.........................)
    
    
}
```

Comment: You have to show some effort. Do your homework.

Comment: This is not a program, and is barely a question.  _"its hard for me"_ does not describe an engineering problem.  On top of all the missing parts of the program and syntax errors, I see no reason to use linked lists to address your specified functionality.  I also see nothing that matches your question's title of "backward".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you will build the fundamental function for this list
you can use "for each" function to do your task:

```
int SlistForeach(node_t from, node_t to , action_func_t 
action_func, void *param)
{
    int stat = 1;
    node_t index = from;
    assert(NULL != to);
    assert(NULL != from);

    while(index != to)
    {
        stat = action_func(&(index->data), param);
        if(0 == stat)
        {
            return (stat);
        }
        index = index->next;
    }

    return(stat);
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `index != to->next' because you do wanna include the `to` in your check.

Comment: thats Depends on implementation